# Where have "predefined SMS messages" gone in Android 5?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop

I bought a Motorola smartphone two years ago with Android 4.4. Previously I had an HTC with Android 2.6. with which I could (and did) use predefined SMS messages (such as "Sorry, late, bla bla bla", "Hi, what's up?").

I couldn't find the option in 4.4 and in 5 either, now that I can upgrade my phone to Lollipop. Are those options gone?

For the sake of curiosity and thoroughness (and since the choice is offered to me) I tried selecting Hangouts as my "preferred" SMS app, in the hope another application, another set of options, maybe "predefined SMS messages" lie there... Not only did I *not* find what I was looking for but also selecting "Hangouts" as my favourite SMS app... disables SMS messages. Wtf? ( <-- that's me sounding perplexed). Go figure.

So have Google developers decided predefined messages were "so has been" or is there an option hidden somewhere?

Comment: I don't know that Android has ever had this. It may have been something HTC added.

Comment: I sought the internet and Android indeed did have such a feature at least once. So I am almost certain it was not bound to HTC only.

Comment: Also, regarding Hangout, SMS isn't gone at all. It's just that, by default, Hangout [merges Hangout and SMS conversations into a single thread](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/6005073?hl=en). This can be changed in the setting if you don't like the merged conversation.

Comment: @LieRyan it's not that SMS is gone; with Hangouts selected as the SMS application, *all* the options that relate to SMS are disabled (i.e. greyed and non-clickable). Hence my perplexity upon the relevance of Hangouts for SMS.

Answer (score 1):

You should look in the Phone/Dialer app, not SMS/Hangout app. This is from stock Nexus 6 Lollipop:

1. Open the Phone app

   [image]
2. Tap the overflow menu besides the search box and tap "Settings":

   [image]
3. Tap "General"

   [image]
4. Tap "Quick Responses":

   [image]
5. Edit your quick responses editing the text box that pops up when you tap on the list view:

   [image]

Comment: Aren't those quick responses for phone calls that you can't answer, not *text messages* that you can't answer?

Comment: As far as I can tell, stock Android never has canned message. That is probably HTC's addition.

Comment: Thanks for the tip LieRyan. However I cannot add any message to the list (I can see no option to do that, nothing that allows it in the menu). Moreover I have no hint to it when I want to compose a new SMS. Am I missing something?